# Should I split long result sql-queries for chunks for SQLServer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, .net-core

I have a table with more than 100 of millions rows.
The task is handle it row by row (keeping cursor of the handled row somewhere).
The current approach is the following: SqlConnection + SqlReader which fetches all the data from the sql server and handles it row by row:

```
SELECT id, value
FROM MyTable
WHERE id > {cursorId}
```

What are bad sides of this approach? I know only one: that the sql-connection should be alive. Does it spends much resources on the sql-server side?

I have an idea to split it on chunks. But I have to prove that this way is better.

I have an Sqlserver instance 2017.

Comment: 100 millions of rows, that can take some time. Is it possible that the rows change during that operation ? (delete / add rows ?)

Comment: The term "cursor" has a specific meaning in T-SQL; they're the things you get from `DECLARE CURSOR` statements, which you are apparently (and hopefully) not using, as the performance of those sucks. Processing data in chunks by keeping track of where you were last time is a fairly common technique; one thing to watch out for is that your view of the data this way is not consistent if rows are deleted (or inserted with lower IDs, when it's not an identity).

Comment: What do you mean by "keep cursor of the handled row"? `Sqldatareader` streams results to the client as fast as the app can consume them, sometimes called a "firehose" cursor. Generally there is no need to return such results in batches.

Comment: Please tell me there is a good reason for this. Based on your sample query, I really don't see a need for it. A set based operation is the way to go, but with that many rows, even set based could be painful without pagination. We are going to need a little more info from you.

Comment: As for resource use, it pays to read as quickly as possible. If you're going to use the output to do something that takes a lot of time per row, it makes more sense to read all of the output client side first, then process it.

Comment: Actually the task is to move data from sqlserver to another one. And for each row I make a call of the external resource. Is it okay to keep sqlreader open when for each row I make such calls? I can't find some reasonable answer.

Comment: It's OK in that nothing will break. It's sub-optimal in two ways: SQL Server will need to maintain some memory and row locks as long as you're busy reading, and the DBA will see `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` waits pop up if the client doesn't read the results quickly enough. The latter is harmless in itself if the client really is just slow, but might cause some fruitless investigation into problems. Unless the client is very short on memory and can't fetch all rows in one go, it rarely makes sense to keep open a data reader for slow row-by-row processing.

Comment: **Actually the task is to move data from sqlserver to another one.** Is this a *one-time-action*? It might be better to link both servers and move the data directly. You might think about replication... *Row-by-row* is - in almost any case - the worst choice...

Comment: Have you tried using SSIS?

Comment: No. I have to put data not to sqlserver. There is no database at all on the end side. There is only way to make rpc call.